# Angular - How to have a variable shared by all views (displayed in header)

Tags: angularjs, mean

So I am working on a really simple gallery app. I am using the MEAN stack. Basically I have a view where I list all pictures and a view where I upload a new picture. In the header I want to have the total picture count. I did it by creating a controller for the header. It works and I get everything correctly. When I upload a new picture it redirects me to the view with all pictures and I can see my new picture added. However the count in the header doesn't change until refresh. If the pictures are 6 total, when I add a new one the count doesn't refresh. How can I fix this? I tried saving the picture count in my header controller as well as in my picture controller. Here is my code: 
Pictures Controller:

```
(() => {
angular.module('gallery').controller('Pictures', ['Picture', function (Picture) {
    let pictures = this;

    Picture.all().success((data) => {
        pictures.pictures = data;
        pictures.pictureCount = data.length;
    });

    }]); 
})();
```

I tried using a header controller before that. Used ng-controller in my header div. Didn't work as well. Any suggestions, solutions or practices are welcome!

Comment: Add picture count in rootScope then rootScope will be available in every controller.

Comment: @AfnanNazir Will try it now. However where is the best place to do that. As far as I know I should use .run and pass the $rootScope. Where in my files is the best place to to that?

Comment: You are right but in your case it looks its not necessary to declare run. you can update/add/access rootScope across controllers without declaring in run. As far as best practice it is discouraged to use rootScope unless its last choice. You should use services to share data across controllers.

Comment: @AfnanNazir $rootScope looks like a solution. Although I will read up some more on using services to share data across controllers since I want to follow the best practices. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Share the count variable between two controllers through factory/service.

```
        angular.module('myModule', [])
            .service('Picture', function () {
                var self = this;
                self.obj = {};
            });

        angular.module('myModule')
        .controller('Pictures', ['Picture', function (Picture) {
                let pictures = this;

                Picture.all().success((data) => {
                    pictures.pictures = data;
                    Picture.obj.pictureCount = data.length;
                });

            }]);

        angular.module('myModule')
        .controller('headerCtrl', ['Picture', function (Picture) {
                let pictures = this;

                pictures.obj = Picture.obj;

            }]);
```

In header view you can simply use

```
<div ng-controller="headerCtrl as header">
    <div> {{header.obj.pictureCount}} </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $rootScope, but it's not recommended to pollute the global name space like this. Better to implement a service for the sharing of data.

Create another module like this:

```
angular.module('utils',[])
    .service('shared', service);

function service(){
    this.data = {};
    return this;
}
```

You can then inject this service into each of your modules

angular.module(name, [
    angularMeteor
    ,'ui.router'
    ,'utils'
])

In your controller you inject shared, and in your code you can use

```
this.shared.data.myVariable = "something"
```

or

```
$scope.shared.data.myVariable = "something"
```

And you can use that from other controllers as you like.